# How to calculate other 2 coords in google maps with azimuth degree and distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google maps v3 api and i've only coordinate (latlng) which is 22.75297222, 75.86708333 and i want to create triangle in 240 degree azimuth direction which is 10 km long

Is there any formula or codes ???

I want idea how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the computeOffset() method of the [geometry library:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry)

> Given a particular heading, an origin location, and the distance to travel (in meters), you can calculate the destination coordinates using computeOffset().